# Using 32bit Bitmap for Toobar?

Tags: winapi, bitmap, toolbar, alphablending

We do use a Toolbar that is created with the Win32 CreateToolbarEx() function. Currently it uses a 24bit Bitmap for displaying the Buttons. Is there any possibility to use a 32bit Bitmap with Alpha blending for better displaying the Background of the toolbar buttons? Are 32bit Bitmaps with Alpha blending supported by this Toolbar?

Comment: If you use an imagelist (via `TB_SETIMAGELIST`) rather than a bitmap I think it should work.

Comment: We do draw some 32bit Icons into a bitmap. Then we create the toolbar with this bitmap. Built with VC2013 and IcoFx. Testing on Windows7 and 10 is ok. The alpha value is fine in the toolbar. Great.